# @yield('title') why can't it move to the center

Tags: css, laravel

I have been trying this for the past few hours and it for some reason, my title won't move in the center. Is it because I am using yield or something? Also I tried putting it in the head tag using title tag but nothing happen so I have to use a h3 tag, but it won't let me move center.

I have tried many different method but still doesn't work such as:

```
#center-text ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

padding-right

margin
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">



    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/title.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">


                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @include('layouts.testSidebar')

                    <!-- Branding Image -->

                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <div id="center-text">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" id="nav-center">
                            <li>
                                <h3>@yield('title')</h3>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue" style="color:white">
                                    <b>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue" style="color: white">
                                            <b>Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text-align: center` ?

Comment: Yup just tried that still doesn't work

Comment: Could it be because of the place where i put yield('title')? Or the title.css?

Comment: Try this: `#nav-center li h3 {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  text-align: center;
}`

Comment: @HirenGohel sorry but that doesn't work as well

Comment: Does modifying your code like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEQjvQ) help ?

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, I guess the closest was developernator code which help but it affected my navbar so im trying to fixed now, but anyways thanks a lot for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `h3` try using bootstraps built in class of `text-center`

Example:

```
<h3 class="text-center">@yield('title')</h3>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment

Comment: When I try to remove the ul and li tag and used your code, it worked, but the navbar became bigger and thicker

Comment: @Dkna, of course it did, you're using a `<h3>` tag.

Comment: So what tag should I used? I tried using title tag but it doesn't appear and when I remove the h3 tag and just use yield('title') it became really small and also the navbar height just decreased a bit @Option

Comment: You could change to `<h4>` maybe? Worse ways add a class to the tag and give it your own custom styling.

Comment: I see well i guess I could try the custom styling, thanks a lot for your explanation @Option